# qTip tooltip does not appear, jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, qtip

I have a site that displays items, 12 items per page and I can paginate through the pages using jquery. On the same page I implemented a the tooltip feature with qTip.

Hovering over the items some information appear. That works until I use the paginator to go to the next page.

The pagination reloads the content. But it has the same structure as when I refresh the page.

Here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".cornerize").corner("5px");
 $('a#verd').live('click', exSite);
 $("a.tp").live('click', thumpsUp);
 $("a#next").click(getProgramms);
 $("a#previous").click(getProgramms);
 $("a#page").each(function() {
  $(this).click(getProgramms);
 });

 $('a.ppname[rel]').each(function(){

    $(this).qtip( {
     content : {url :$(this).attr('rel')},
     position : {
      corner : {
       tooltip : 'leftBottom',
       target : 'rightBottom'
      }
     },
     style : {
      border : {
       width : 5,
       radius : 10
      },
      padding : 10,
      textAlign : 'center',
      tip : true, 
      name : 'cream' 
     }

    });
   });

 });
```

The html/dom does not change:

```
<a class="ppname" rel="link" href="#">...</a>
```

qTip takes from every a.ppname the rel value end loads the content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because new elements are not automatically "qTiped" when they are loaded after page load. For regular events, you would have to use `.live()` instead of `.bind()`.

This has been solved before (judging from the comment): [Problem with qTip - Tips not showing because elements load after the script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005521/problem-with-qtip-tips-not-showing-because-elements-load-after-the-script).

The correct way to do it is (from that answer):

```
$('a.ppname[rel]').live('mouseover', function() {
    var target = $(this);
    if (target.data('qtip')) { return false; }

    target.qtip({
        overwrite: false, // Make sure another tooltip can't overwrite this one without it being explicitly destroyed
        show: {
            ready: true // Needed to make it show on first mouseover event
        },
        content : {url :$(this).attr('rel')},
        position : {
            corner : {
                tooltip : 'leftBottom',
                target : 'rightBottom'
            }
        },
        style : {
            border : {
            width : 5,
            radius : 10
        },
        padding : 10,
        textAlign : 'center',
        tip : true, 
        name : 'cream' 
    });

    target.trigger('mouseover');
});
```

Comment: this solution works but the tooltips are display wrong, sometimes they are displaye and sometimes not. here is my question on that problem http://stackoverflow.com/users/401025/artworkad

Comment: Ah, you're right! I left part of the solution out :$ I think it should be better now.

Comment: but seems to be a little slower now, some items have to be hovered twice to display the tooltip. I get a url from rel and load some content from a php server to display the tooltip maybe its because of that? I tested it now, every link has to be hovered exactly twice to get the tooltip

Comment: In that case, did you include the `show: {ready: true}` and the `target.trigger('mouseover');` at the bottom?

Comment: hi, I am facing a strange problem now. Sometimes, seems to when I hover the items very fast (I am not sure) the tooltips do not close...any ideas on that?