# Tooltip (qTip) is not closed, jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, qtip, jquery-ui-tooltip

with following code [qTip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/) works for me and generates tooltips:

```
$('a.ppname[rel]').live('mouseover', function() {
    $(this).qtip( {
     content : {
      url : $(this).attr('rel')
     },
     position : {
      corner : {
       tooltip : 'leftBottom',
       target : 'rightBottom'
      }
     },
     style : {
      border : {
       width : 5,
       radius : 10
      },
      padding : 10,
      textAlign : 'center',
      tip : true, // Give it a speech bubble tip with
      // automatic corner detection
      name : 'cream' // Style it according to the preset
     // 'cream' style
     }

    });
  });
 });
```

But the qTip is not removed from the dom, well sometimes it just disappears and appears again and I get a lot of opened tooltips:

[image]

I looked at the dom, the qtip seems not to be removed but just set invisible. I need some simple logic to destroy the tooltip. E.g. if `a.ppname` was focused and is not focused any more I could destroy it. But how would that look like in javascript? Any Ideas?

**Update**: I downgraded my jQuery to 1.3.2 [recommended for qTip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/download/#). I don't get tooltips that stay open anymore but there is another problem now:

[image]

The tooltips, which for now I can not delete seem to appear when I hover the next item. Please, provide some suggestions how to destroy the tooltip.

**Update**: using

```
$('a.ppname[rel]').each(function(){
```

in the first line of the code the problem is solved. But that leads to another problem another problem that I describe here [qTip tooltip does not appear, jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4408415/qtip-tooltip-does-not-appear-jquery). seems to be a dilemma^:D

Comment: You should always link to the plugin's page, doubly so when the plugin is a homonym with a cotton stick for cleaning your ears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the tooltip from the DOM by calling the `destroy` method when the tooltip is hidden. Try this (kudos to Matt for his example that I copied and ammended):

```
$('a.ppname[rel]').qtip({
   content : {stuff},
   style : {stuff},
   position: {stuff},
   show: 'mouseover',
   hide: 'mouseout',
   onHide: function() { $(this).qtip('destroy'); }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want is

```
$('a.ppname[rel]').qtip({
   content : {stuff},
   style : {stuff},
   position: {stuff},
   show: 'mouseover',
   hide: 'mouseout'
})
```

Comment: hm, this does not work. The tooltips are still in the dom, and some of them again are not disappearing. I am searching for a method to remove them from the dom after a.ppname lost the focus, or the mouse is no longer moving over a.ppname